# full calendar event vertical sort in month view where longer durations are at the bottom

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, postgresql, fullcalendar

I am trying to get the full calendar to sort events so that the single day events come to the top of the stack and the multiple day events come to the bottom of the stack where they are still sorted by start time. I am wondering about how to do it?

for example for this data:

```
[{id: '1',title: '1',color:'*',url:'*',tip: '*',start: new Date(2015,0,6,6,0),end: new Date(2015,0,7,8,55)},

{id: '2',title: '2',color:'*',url:'*',tip: '*',start: new Date(2015,0,6,7,55),end: new Date(2015,0,7,10,50)}]
```

in this link:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231902/jquery-fullcalendar-event-sorting
```

it is saying that it is impossible, but i beg to differ because it claims it puts 10x importance to the duration whereas i could not find any code regarding it in the actual fullcalendar.js.

I have tried sql sorting but everytime the script resorts and puts the longer durations at the top from some functions that i cant find.

any help or hint greatly appreciated. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
=> SELECT * FROM calsort ORDER BY id;
 id |         starts         |          ends          
----+------------------------+------------------------
  1 | 2015-01-05 16:47:43+00 | 2015-01-05 17:47:43+00
  2 | 2015-01-03 16:48:57+00 | 2015-01-04 16:48:57+00
  3 | 2015-01-03 14:48:44+00 | 2015-01-04 15:48:44+00
  4 | 2015-01-05 14:48:05+00 | 2015-01-05 16:48:05+00
(4 rows)

=> SELECT * FROM calsort ORDER BY (CASE WHEN date(ends)=date(starts) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END), starts, id;
 id |         starts         |          ends          
----+------------------------+------------------------
  4 | 2015-01-05 14:48:05+00 | 2015-01-05 16:48:05+00
  1 | 2015-01-05 16:47:43+00 | 2015-01-05 17:47:43+00
  3 | 2015-01-03 14:48:44+00 | 2015-01-04 15:48:44+00
  2 | 2015-01-03 16:48:57+00 | 2015-01-04 16:48:57+00
(4 rows)
```

Comment: thanks @Richard Huxton, i have already tried sorting the events using sql, but fullcalendar.js goes through the events and resorts them using some function i couldnt find. i was assuming it would be compareSlotSegs, but this function actually sorts by start time first, but in the view, the longer duration for some reason always comes at the top using some a function i cant find. any help would be appreciated.